# 表示されているフォントを知る方法はありますか？

Tags: css, html5, font

下記画像のようにChromeデベロッパーツールでFontを調べてみました。

`Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, ...` とあるのは、ブラウザーがArialがあれば、Arialを使う、なければ、Helvetica Neueを使う、と順に搭載されているフォントがあれば使うよっていう命令だと思うのですが、今知りたいのはこの順番ではなくて、表示されている文字にどのフォントが適用されているのか知りたいのですが、わかる方法はありますでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Elements`タブを開き、右側の`Computed`タブを開くと、一番下に`Rendered Fonts`が記載されています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]